# How to accept binary input from user in C++?

Tags: c++, binary, bit

I want to do a binary operation in C++, namely XOR, on a binary input given by the user. The user will enter a sequence of zeros and ones only. How can I declare a variable to accept the input 1's and 0's as binary bits?

Comment: Read as string, and then verify the input.

Comment: I am actually a beginner in C++ and programming too. How can I verify the input? And for what purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A convenient way is to use [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset). If you have a look at its [constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset), there are options to construct a bit set from several data sources including `std::string` and C-style strings. Constructors validate the input and throw an exception in case invalid input is given.

You can then use its [bitwise operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_logic2) directly. XOR is `operator^`.

`std::bitset` is a fixed-size container, so you'll have to specify the maximum expected length as a `constexpr` value.

Comment: I am not sure if bitset enables me to have the user specify the length of the input sequence?!

Comment: Will constexpr enable variable size sequence? The program I want to have asks the user to enter the length of the sequence before entering the sequence itself.

Comment: @MohamedAhmed As I said, the size is fixed, that is, known at compile time. This can be just a maximum, e.g. 256 bits. The user just enters the string representation that should not be longer than that.

Answer (score 0):

get the sequence as a string, then use strtol with base 2 | or create your own function to convert the string into a integer (that's not really difficult) | or use the string directly (string[i]-'0')^...

Open your mind ;)